# responsive css in bootstrap grid for responsive columns folding for large, medium, small screen

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

what should be the usage mix of md- xl- etc used in col class in bootstrap to get following responsive folding behavior?

wide screen:

```
+---+---+----+----+
| A | B | C  | D  |
+---+---+----+----+
| 1 | 2 | 3  | 4  |
+---+---+----+----+
| a | b | c  | d  |
+---+---+----+----+
```

narrower screen:

```
+----+----+
| A  | B  |
+----+----+
| 1  | 2  |
+----+----+
| a  | b  |
+----+----+
| C  | D  |
+----+----+
| 3  | 4  |
+----+----+
| c  | d  |
+----+----+
```

smallest mobile screen:

```
+-----+
| A   |
+-----+
| 1   |
+-----+
| a   |
+-----+
| B   |
+-----+
| 2   |
+-----+
| b   |
+-----+
| C   |
+-----+
| 3   |
+-----+
| c   |
+-----+
| D   |
+-----+
| 4   |
+-----+
| d   |
+-----+
```

Comment: This is a useful question, but I'm not sure that there is a definition of "proper". Asking this type of question "properly" is quite a puzzle in my opinion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your content appears to be grouped into four columns (A1a, B2b, ...), each with three rows. Starting with the columns you can put each of group of rows within its own div column container. Using divs you don't need to further separate them into rows since by default the divs will occupy 100% of the width available to them, but you could if needed.

Using Bootstrap's column layout you can specify 4 of them for large screens, 2 on medium, and one on small which would be the default so no specific class is needed.

This worked for me:

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
      <div>A</div>
      <div>1</div>
      <div>a</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
      <div>B</div>
      <div>2</div>
      <div>b</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
      <div>C</div>
      <div>3</div>
      <div>c</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
      <div>D</div>
      <div>4</div>
      <div>d</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```